# UIView frame when navigation bar and tab bar controller exist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a UIView programatically in **loadView**. The application has a UITabBarController and UINavigationController.

How do I create a view that **automatically resizes** when a tab bar and a navigation bar both exist?

My current approach to this problem is calculating the heights of the navigation and tab bar controllers and subtracting them from the mainScreen's height:

```
float navObjectsHeight = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height 
    + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;

CGRect mainFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenFrame.size.width, 
  screenFrame.size.height - navObjectsHeight);

UIView *contentWrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:mainFrame];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UIView has a property to handle that situation. As you are creating it programatically the code to use is:

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] init];
aView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: I have had success with the autoresizingMask when creating table views programatically, but not when creating UIViews in loadView.

Comment: make sure the containing view's frame has the apropriate values. If that doesn't work, then I think you could provide more details.

Comment: I think the problems I was having were to do with the way in which I was initialising views in loadView. Often it's best to invoke [super loadView] and then instantiate a wrapper view with frame self.view.bounds. Then the autoresizing mask will resize to account for the tab bar controller.